# Pattern matching SQL on first 5 characters

Tags: sql, pattern-matching, ansi-sql-92

I'm thinking about a SQL query that returns me all entries from a column whose first 5 characters match. Any ideas? 
I'm thinking about entries where ANY first 5 characters match, not specific ones. E.g.

```
HelloA
HelloB
ThereC
ThereD
Something
```

would return the first four entries:

```
HelloA
HelloB
ThereC
ThereD
```

EDIT: I am using SQL92 so cannot use the left command!

Comment: Use `substring` for the left command... [link](http://www.postgresql.jp/document/pg702doc/user/x2732.htm)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE LEFT(stringColumn, 5) IN (
    SELECT LEFT(stringColumn, 5)
    FROM YOURTABLE
    GROUP BY LEFT(stringColumn, 5)
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```

<kbd>[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1935/5)</kbd>

This selects the first 5 characters, groups by them and returns only the ones that happen more than once.

Or with Substring:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable 
WHERE substring(stringColumn,1,5) IN (
  SELECT substring(stringColumn,1,5)
  FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY substring(stringColumn,1,5)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
;
```

<kbd>[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1935/9)</kbd>

Comment: please see my edited question. I meant any first 5 characters, not specific ones, so probably cannot use like.

Comment: @MJP. Updated my answer. see if it is what you want. And usually it is a good idea to put the tag of the flavour of sql you are using in the question.

Comment: done! I think in my version of DBMS, I cannot use the left command!

Answer (score 8):

Sounds easy enough...

In SQL Server this would be something along the lines of

```
where Left(ColumnName,5) = '12345'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select *
From tbl t1
Where exists (
    Select 1
    From tbl t2
    Where left(t1.str, 5) = left(t2.str)
    Group by left(t2.str, 5)
    Having count(1) > 1
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS. If it supports Windowed Aggregate functions it's:

```
select *
from 
  (
    select
       tab.*, 
       count(*) over (partition by substring(col from 1 for 5) as cnt
    from tab
  ) as dt
where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to work with a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) approach.

Something like this:

```
with CountriesCTE(Id, Name)
as (
select Id, Name from Countries
)
select distinct Countries.Name
from CountriesCTE, Countries
where left(CountriesCTE.Name,5) = left(Countries.Name,5) and CountriesCTE.Id <> Countries.Id
```